# "Attempt to read property "titulo" on string" Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

No matter what I do this error keeps popping up, I´ve searched for a solution but Im too stupid to comprehend what is going on, please help me

preguntas.blade.php

```php
@extends('app')
@section('title', 'Pregunta:'.$nombrePregunta->titulo)
@section('description', $nombrePregunta->categorias->nombre)
@section('content')
<div class="leading-loose max-w-4xl mb-4">
   {{$nombrePregunta->body}}
</div>
```

There´s more but its non important

Routes/web.php

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\paginaControlador;

Route::get('/', [paginaControlador::Class, 'gestionHome'])->name('home');
Route::get('/categorias/{nombreCategoria:slug}', [paginaControlador::class, 'gestionCategoria'])->name('categoria');
Route::get('/etiquetas/{nombreEtiqueta:slug}', [paginaControlador::class, 'gestionEtiqueta'])->name('etiqueta');
Route::get('/preguntas/{nombrePregunta:slug}', [paginaControlador::class, 'gestionPregunta'])->name('pregunta');
```

Controllers/paginaControlador.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Preguntas;
use App\Models\Categorias;
use App\Models\Etiquetas;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class paginaControlador extends Controller
{
    public function gestionHome(){
        $preguntas = Preguntas::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate();
        return view("home", compact('preguntas'));
    }
    public function gestionCategoria($nombreCategoria){
        $preguntas = $nombreCategoria->preguntas()->orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate();
        return view('categoria', compact('nombreCategoria','preguntas'));
    }
    public function gestionEtiqueta($nombreEtiqueta){
        $preguntas = $nombreEtiqueta->preguntas()->orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate();
        return view('etiqueta', compact('nombreEtiqueta','preguntas'));
    }
    public function gestionPregunta($nombrePregunta){
        return view('preguntas', compact('nombrePregunta'));
    }
}
```

Models/preguntas.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Preguntas extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    // 1:N
    public function comentarios(){
        return $this -> hasMany(Comentarios::class);
    }
    // N:N
    public function etiquetas(){
        return $this -> belongsToMany(Etiquetas::class);
    }
    //N1
    public function categorias(){
        return $this -> belongsTo(Categorias::class);
    }
    //N1
    public function user(){
        return $this -> belongsTo(User::class);
    }

}
```

I dont know if this is useful but ill put it here just in case

PreguntasFactory

```php
namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Categorias;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\Preguntas>
 */
class PreguntasFactory extends Factory
{
    
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'categorias_id' => Categorias::factory(),
            'user_id' => User::factory(),
            'titulo' => $title = fake()->unique()->sentence(),
            'slug' => Str::slug($title),
            'body' => fake()->text(1300)
        ];
    }
}
```

I´ve tried using this [live.ERROR: Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\core\resources\views\user\signal-all.blade.php)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67258669/live-error-trying-to-get-property-title-of-non-object-view-c-xampp-htdocs), but i can´t comprehend what i need to do

Comment: @section('title', 'Pregunta:'.$nombrePregunta->titulo)
had you verfied it's value ?
and had you confirmed you can pass dynamic data to section title ?

Comment: `$nombrePregunta` is of type string. Did you `@dump()` it? Your route takes a `{nombrePregunta:slug}` parameter, which I think would be the string shown

Comment: @brombeer how do i dump it?

Comment: @khayamKhan I don´t know how to verify it I´m sorry

Comment: Use `@dd($nombrePregunta)` (in your view) to dump it and end the script or `@dump($nombrePregunta)` to simply dump it and continue the script

Comment: Found the solution in Controllers/paginaControlador.php 
```php
    public function gestionPregunta(Pregunta $nombrePregunta){
        return view('preguntas', compact('nombrePregunta'));
    }
```
Without "Pregunta" in there it didnt make an object

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you want to use the "magic" of [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-model-binding), but you do not define a model in the input parameter `$nombrePregunta` of the controller method `gestionPregunta` (and same problem is in other controller methods).

```
public function gestionPregunta(Preguntas $nombrePregunta){
    return view('preguntas', compact('nombrePregunta'));
}
```

Edit based on your comment:

If you are using other routeKeyName (in your case slug), you have to also set it in your model (Preguntas).

```
public function getRouteKeyName(): string
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

If you dont want to change routeKeyName, than you have to manually find in controller method the coresponding model for slug:

```
public function gestionPregunta($nombrePregunta){
    $nombrePregunta = Preguntas::where('slug', $nombrePregunta)->firstOrFail();
    return view('preguntas', compact('nombrePregunta'));
}
```

Comment: The routes take a slug parameter `{nombrePregunta:slug}` though, not the object itself

Comment: It is ok, so you have to also change routeKeyName in model https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#customizing-the-key

Comment: Thank you for your help even though it was a stupid error

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in Controllers/paginaControlador.php

```php
    public function gestionPregunta(Pregunta $nombrePregunta){
        return view('preguntas', compact('nombrePregunta'));
    }
```

Without "Pregunta" in there it didnt make an object